# Blender game engine movements

Tags: game-engine

I used to do animation but just started creating games using blender.
I am pretty sure my problem is minor but it would be a great help if you got assist me.
My problem is that i created an armature and a walk cycle and stand cycle.
My walk cycle has no problem in the game except for the stand cycle.
Means that , whenever i press w to walk front , it has the action of it ... but when i add another movement which the sensor is "always" (in the game logic )
Which the action will happen once my character stop walking .... but that is where the problem started . I press p to play and the stand action works well... but when i press "W" .... the character froze and didnt walk front ... I know that my explaination of my problems is not really understandable... but please take alook at this blend.file which my problem lies inside.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/7c1ib6pfmxej7d6/walk+cycle.blend

Go to blender game engine ... and press p . You will see my character standing with movement but once you press w ... it stop... i want it to move .. 
My character can move front if i dele my stand action...
How to add both of it ??
Thx for reading and helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each item can have one active action attached to it. To expand this for the game engine you can merge all actions into one.

In the action logic brick you can set the start and end frames so you can play only part of the action as desired. Use the priority to choose which movement overrides the other.

[image]